# Record Voice and Speak & Listen to Live Chats While in Lock Screen Mode and While Visting Other Apps

Tags: android, ios, locking, screen, agora.io

We are currently using Agora Voice SDK for voice recording and live voice chat on iOS and Android apps, which is working well so far in terms of sound quality. In order to improve our user's experience further, we are wondering if it is possible to:

Record voice and speak & listen to live chats while the phone is in lock screen mode or while visiting other apps?

As of now, our users cannot record their voices (recording pauses) and speak & listen to live chats (sound disconnects) while their phones are in lock screen mode or while visiting other apps, which sometimes could be quite frustrating - if this is possible with Agora Voice SDK, we would really like to implement that functionality.

Looking forward to hearing back from you!

Best Regards,

Carl Fridell

Answer (score 0):

by default, you should be able to speak while the phone is in locked state or while visiting other apps using Agora Video SDK. If you can't achieve that, please file a JIRA ticket here so that we can look at your implementation: 
https://agora-ticket.agora.io/form/69/issue/aedc3ca1-72fc-4651-96a8-3a68d49456b0. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the answer Shaocheng! We are not using Agora Video SDK, but only Agora Voice SDK - would that make any difference in terms of being able to make voice recordings and speak & listen to live chats while the app is backgrounded?